# How to add categories and products from admin and how to show at front end of the website?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using magento version 1.7 , I created some categories and products[image]

but both are not visible at customer end as you can see in below image..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look @

[Creating and Assigning Root Categories to Store](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/catalog/creating_and_assigning_root_categories)

[Magento Adding a New Category and Product (youtube)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L4VN66Bjsfs)

You also need to clear those 'yellowish' warning at top of page and clear cache

Answer (score 0):

Clear your var/cache and reindex your data through admin pannel.